# Ubuntu 22.04 allow VNC server connection from LiveUSB image?

Tags: networking, server, remote-desktop, vnc

So, I need to install Ubuntu on a machine, and I booted Ubuntu Desktop (Gnome) LiveUSB image there.

The user `ubuntu` there by default has no password, so I had to so `sudo passwd ubuntu` in order to allow ssh login into this machine.

So, I wanted to have a VNC connection to the desktop; unfortunately (but to be expected, people are shit), the Internet is full with shitty, stupid advice like https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-22-04

> Once that installation completes, install the TightVNC server:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install tightvncserver
> ```

Ok:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ tightvncserver
tightvncserver: command not found

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install tightvncserver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tightvncserver
```

Thank you very much for the great, updated information! `/s`

Then I found https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers :

> Vino is the default VNC server in Ubuntu to share your existing desktop with other users.
>
> To configure vino from within GNOME, go to System > Preferences > Remote Desktop

Well, in Ubuntu 22.04 the path is "Settings"/"Sharing" - but they should probably change that as soon as possible, so it is outdated by next year, so all of us can waste even more hours looking for obscure settings.

Anyways, I got to a screen like this one (from https://linuxhint.com/enable-remote-desktop-ubuntu-access-windows/):

[image: Remote Desktop]

Except I also checked "Enable Legacy VNC Protocol" and turned on "Remote Control".

So now - from another Ubuntu PC as client, I tried to connect via `xtigervncviewer 192.168.X.Y`; and this is the problem: The very first time I tried this; I got this by the client:

```
Sun Dec 17 09:43:45 2023
 DecodeManager: Detected 2 CPU core(s)
 DecodeManager: Creating 2 decoder thread(s)
 CConn:       Connected to host 192.168.X.Y port 5900
 CConn:       End of stream
 CConn:       The connection was dropped by the server before the session could
              be established.
```

... HOWEVER, in the LiveUSB OS, I got some sort of a stupid popup "Would you like to allow the connection" or something - I just move the mouse to see what the options are, and the stupid popup DISAPPEARED, and now it will NOT be raised anymore - regardless of how many times I call `xtigervncviewer 192.168.X.Y`.

So how can I get this stupid popup to show up again, so I can give permission, so I can use VNC remote desktop on LiveUSB Ubuntu 22.04 session?